# Quora-like expandable component in React Native

Tags: react-native, frontend, expandablelistview, quora

I'm trying to build a React Native app and would like to implement a component just like in Quora where upon clicking the question, the component expands and shows the remaining details (text/images of the question).

I tried using react-native-panel from https://github.com/dwicao/react-native-panel#readme, but it can only handle text in the panel before expanding. I'd like to implement a panel that has an image in it even before I press on the panel to expand. Would love it if anyone could refer me to any npm packages that use components to achieve this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this tutorial https://blog.theodo.com/2020/06/build-accordion-list-react-native/. Stick the desired image somewhere there in the code.